# NullPointerException in array of objects

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

this is program to ask inputs from user: name of 5 students and addresses 
 by creating arrays of objects and displaying them.

```
package StringDisplay;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Student {


    String name;
    String address;
    Student[] studentArray = new Student[5];


    public void setInfo() {
        Scanner userName = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            Student student = new Student();


            System.out.print("Enter Name:");
            student.name = userName.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Enter Address:");
            student.address = userName.nextLine();
            studentArray[i] = student;


        }
    }


    public void displayInfo() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Student student = studentArray[i];
            System.out.print("NAME:" + student.name);
            System.out.print("ADDRESS:" + student.address);
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student info = new Student();
        info.setInfo();
        Student display = new Student();
        display.displayInfo();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Student info = new Student();
    info.setInfo();
    Student display = new Student();
    display.displayInfo();
```

Read Simple English of that code you are making object "info" of Student Class and setting info in that....

and then making new object of Student class "display" so basically there is nothing in display object to display for you because all info is saved in info object.

Hope you got the problem...